# how to tell views "do not theme the row data"

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a view that with row-style set to "fields".  Rather than theme the individual rows the normal way -- i.e. with style, row, and field templates -- I would like to extract certain information from each row, bundle up the extracted information as a json object, and then pass the json object to a script.  The script will then render all the row-data.

I created a custom template, views-view-unformatted--myview.tpl.php with the following code:

```
<?php
$rowdata = array()
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
  dsm ("row $key: "); dsm ($row);
  $rowdata[$key] = dostuff($row);
}
?>
```

Unfortunately, I discovered that $row is no longer an object (which is what I need).  It has already been rendered as an html string.

How do I tell views "please do not render the individual rows.  I need access to the row data"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a views plugin.  The approach is similar to what is described here http://groups.drupal.org/node/10129, in the section "Writing Views 2 Style and Row Plugins".  I created a style plugin (but not a row plugin), and in the style definition I set 'uses row plugin' to false.  I was then able to access the row data from within my style template.  This allowed me to bundle up all my rows as json objects.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the style output template, you should use the row style output template. So your template file should be something like views-view-fields--your-view.tpl.php. Just look under the "Row style out" heading in Theming information" for the template name that you should use. In that template you will get the $row raw object.

Comment: I don't see how that works for me, but perhaps I am missing something.  I need to bundle up all the rowdata into a single json object.  For example, the desired json object might look like:  [{title: 'row-0-title', nid: 100}, ... {title: 'row-5-title', nid: 105}].  If I use the views-view-fields template to create a json-object for each row, how would I then combine them all into a single json object?